# com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.ClientSideClob causes 500 error, apps are unusable

Tags: jpa, jdbc, odata, google-cloud-sql, olingo

Woke up this morning with this error coming from google.cloud.sql.jdbc

We have been using the OData library Oligno v2 for months and for no apparent reason this morning it stopped working. Our apps and services are down.

> {"error":{"code":null,"message":{"lang":"en","value":"\"OData - JPA
>   Runtime: JPA query syntax is not correct\""},"innererror":"class
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException : \nException
>   Description: The object [], of class [class
>   com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.ClientSideClob], could not be
>   converted to [class java.lang.String].\nInternal Exception: Exception
>   [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.4.2.v20130514-5956486): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException\nInternal
>   Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid parameter for pos value
>   1\nError Code: 0"}}

Setup:

- java google app engine
- angular app on the front
- Java EE backend with the oligno v2 library https://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata2/download.html
- simply calling something like http://app.server/odata.svc/Tasks returns this error, it's like the oData library is not compatible anymore with GAE and Cloud SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with the connection, here is the discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/Oc-wJvvCXgE

Please fill out this form if issue still persists:
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12066&thanks=12066&ts=1434572430

Comment: thanks for the link, as the OP of that discussion said, the Cloud SQL server began throwing errors with GAE apps running the latest appengine version. Our backend just stopped working right there. Scary stuff.